# Confusion about timezones oracle and django

Tags: python, django, oracle, datetime

I have django app running on ubuntu-14.04 and database is oracle.

The timezones are as follow

django- settings - `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`

ubuntu - `Asia/Kolkata`

oracle dbtimezone - `UTC`
oracle sessiontimezone - `Asia/Kolkata #this is via sqldeveloper`

While storing datetimes into db I am doing following.

`datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Error I get is `time can not be past`.

I don't want to change the code line. I can set the timezone of my Ubuntu or oracle as that is my development env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally setting my local machine's timezone to `UTC` with this `timedatectl set-timezone UTC` particular command worked.

Answer (score 0):

If Django isn't passing the timezone to the Oracle client, then use the [ORA_SDTZ](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-578B5988-31E2-4D0F-ACEA-95C827F6012B) environment variable.  Your SQL Developer session timezone could be very different to what is used in Django.